# How to change angular innerHtml element attributes

Tags: html, angular, hyperlink, innerhtml

I am working on an angular2+ project and often use the [innerHTML] tag to dynamically insert content into my templates. My problem is I have links that I need to open up in a new tab, however, I can't figure out how to change the target to "_blank".

```
<div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let taoys of taoysArray">
        <h3 *ngIf="taoys?.title" [innerHTML]="taoys.title | safeHtml"></h3>
        <p *ngIf="taoys?.text" [innerHTML]="taoys.text | safeHtml"></p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The p tag is where the link shows up.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can set a placeholder that you replace with what you actually want, conditionally. Like this:

```
'<a href target="{target}">link</a>'.replace('{target}', '_blank')
```